# Get the most recent Tags for a project ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the most recent tag_Values for each `ProjectID`.

At the moment I get all with:

```
SELECT t.tag_value, t.tag_desc, u.update_dat_ins AS INSETION_DATE, p.structure_id AS PROJECT_ID
 FROM updated u 
 JOIN project p ON p.project_id = u.project_id  
 JOIN tag t ON t.tag_id = u.tag_id 
 WHERE t.tag_desc LIKE 'Equity%';
```

How to get only the most recent(by `INSERTION_DATE`) `tag_values` for each `productID` back?

**UPDATE**

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| TAG_VALUE TAG_DESC INSERTION_DATE PROJECT_ID |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 200         Equity  17-DEC-13       1        |
| 10012       Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 312         Equity  12-DEC-12       2        |
| 13415       Equity  16-DEC-11       5        |
| 13415       Equity  17-DEC-11       5        |
| 13415       Equity  18-SEPT-13      2        |
| 13415       Equity  16-OCT-10       9        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| TAG_VALUE TAG_DESC INSERTION_DATE PROJECT_ID |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 10012       Equity  14-DEC-14       1        |
| 13415       Equity  17-DEC-11       5        |
| 13415       Equity  18-SEPT-13      2        |
| 13415       Equity  16-OCT-10       9        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ANALYTIC`.

Something like :

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY insertion_date DESC) rn
```

In the outer query, add the `WHERE` condition as `WHERE rn = 1` to get the most recent tag_value.

***Update : Added a complete test case as requested and based on OP's new input***

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 200 TAG_VALUE,    'Equity' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('17-DEC-13','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 1 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 10012 TAG_VALUE, 'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('14-DEC-14','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 1 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 312 TAG_VALUE,   'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('12-DEC-12','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 2 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 13415  TAG_VALUE,'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('16-DEC-11','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 5 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 13415 TAG_VALUE,'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('17-DEC-11','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 5 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 3415 TAG_VALUE, 'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('18-SEP-13','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 2 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 3415  TAG_VALUE,'EQUITY' TAG_DESC, TO_DATE('16-OCT-10','DD-MON-RR') INSERTION_DATE, 9 PROJECT_ID FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT TAG_VALUE, TAG_DESC, INSERTION_DATE, PROJECT_ID FROM(
 10  SELECT A.*,
 11    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PROJECT_ID ORDER BY INSERTION_DATE DESC) RN
 12  FROM data A)
 13  WHERE RN = 1
 14  /

 TAG_VALUE TAG_DE INSERTION PROJECT_ID
---------- ------ --------- ----------
     10012 EQUITY 14-DEC-14          1
      3415 EQUITY 18-SEP-13          2
     13415 EQUITY 17-DEC-11          5
      3415 EQUITY 16-OCT-10          9

SQL>
```

**Update #2 : Explaining the query in words on OP's request**

If you see the inner query, the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function is assigning a rank to the rows for each group of `PROJECT_ID` sorted in `DESCENDING` order of `INSERTION_DATE`. Thus, the most recent record, i.e. the row having the latest date will be on top for each project_id.

Finally, in the outer query, there is a filter to select only those rows which have the rank assigned as 1.

So, you finally get only those records which have latest insertion_date for each project_id.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Could you update your answer with the whole query, because I do not get the last sentence `In the outer query...` .

Comment: Can you post the create and insert statements so that I can write a query.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Sorry, I cannot post a create statement, because I only have read access to the application I am quering from.

Comment: No need for create statement, just post few rows returned by the select statement.

Comment: See my update in the answer. It should get your issue resolved. Good luck!

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! I now moved several times through the query. Could you add an explanation what exactly you are doing? I really would appreciate that!

Comment: I explained the significance of the query, inner and outer query. See the update #2.